# Unicode strings introduced by 'with_items' iterating over object lists defined inplace

Tags: unicode, ansible

I am having several cases of unicode strings ( appearing in the output as u'somestring' ) being passed to ansible's mysql_db command and causing problems.

It seem that this occurs whenever a with_items (or with_indexed_items or others) iterates over a list of variables defined in place:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - { f1: "aaaaaaaaaa", f2: "{{ 'aaaaaaaaaa' }}" }
```

the output is as follows (check 'f2')

```
ok: [local-vm] => (item={'f1': 'aaaaaaaaaa', 'f2': u'aaaaaaaaaa'}) => {
    "item": {
        "f1": "aaaaaaaaaa",
        "f2": "aaaaaaaaaa"
    },
    "msg": {
        "f1": "aaaaaaaaaa",
        "f2": "aaaaaaaaaa"
    }
}
```

After searching for a while, it seems that this fix in Jinja2 might help here...
https://github.com/ntrrgc/jinja2/commit/b815d68462392a51c2280a25ff3b484885f9c9f2?diff=split

I am running ansible 1.9.2 on ubuntu 14.04.
Any ideas or workarounds?